# How can I install psycopg in requirements.txt when setting up pgAdmin development environment

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2, pgadmin

The psycopg python package cannot install, and throws the following error

```
 error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [8 lines of output]
      running dist_info
      creating C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-079osjd6\psycopg_c.egg-info
      writing C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-079osjd6\psycopg_c.egg-info\PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-079osjd6\psycopg_c.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
      writing top-level names to C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-079osjd6\psycopg_c.egg-info\top_level.txt
      writing manifest file 'C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-079osjd6\psycopg_c.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      couldn't run 'pg_config' --includedir: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
      error: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

I am trying to setup pgAdmin development environment on windows 10 virtual environment and while installing the dependencies on rquirements.txt I encountered this error. I installed the others one by one which worked fine but ran into problems with psycopg even after downgrading to python 3.10 from 3.12 and upgrading MsBuild.

Comment: Install the binary package: `pip install "psycopg[binary]"` (for psycopg3) or `pip install psycopg2-binary` (for psycopg2)